# Evaluating an integral: $\int \frac{1}{(x+\sqrt{x+x^2})^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int \frac{1}{(x+\sqrt{x+x^2})^2} dx$$

I don't know how to approach this integral. I tried a few substitutions, but none of them got me to a desirable point.

Comment: This is a good candidate for the Euler substitution, which for this integrand would be $\sqrt{x^2 + x} = x + t$. If you'd like a little more direction w this, let me know, and I'll write up a proper solution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Comment: Alternately, one can complete the square for the quadratic in the radical, which leads to the substitution $\frac{1}{2} \sec \theta = x + \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Have you tried multiplying numerator and denominator by $(\sqrt{x+x^2}-x)^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have if $x>0
 $ $$\int\frac{1}{\left(x+\sqrt{x+x^{2}}\right)^{2}}dx=\int\frac{1}{x^{2}\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}\right)^{2}}dx
 $$ and now put $u=1+1/x
 $, $du=-dx/x^{2}
 $ and so we get $$-\int\frac{1}{\left(1+\sqrt{u}\right)^{2}}du.
 $$ Now put $s=\sqrt{u}
 $, $ds=1/\left(2\sqrt{u}\right)du
 $ and get $$-2\int\frac{s}{\left(s+1\right)^{2}}ds
 $$ which can be split using partial fractions $$-2\int\frac{1}{s+1}ds+2\int\frac{1}{\left(s+1\right)^{2}}ds.
 $$ I think you can get it from here. If $x<-1
 $ you have $$-\int\frac{1}{\left(1-\sqrt{u}\right)^{2}}du
 $$ and you can use the same passage of the first part using $s=-\sqrt{u}
 $.

Comment: How about the values $x<-1$ when you do the first step?

Comment: @user64494 $1+1/x>0$ if $x<-1.$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: No clue; answer was good enough by all means..